# Cancel UICollectionView updates when view is being dismissed

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have recently reported a crash in my app, and I've found out what is happening and I need some help/best practices/best approach to this issue.

I have a pushed `UICollectionViewController` that on `viewDidLoad` queries the server to fetch some data to fill the `UICollectionView`.

My problem here is, if I push this `UICollectionViewController` and then tap the back button fast - the background thread still continues to fetch the server data, but when the data is fetched I update the `UICollectionView` with the `performBatchUpdates()` and my app crashes.

Here it happens because the app is attempting to reload data on a view that's not visible anymore.

What's the best practice here?

Is there any way to "abort" collection view updates if I'm moving back to the previous VC?

something like:

```
if self.isMovingFromParentViewController { /* abort any update here? */ }
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you updateing the collection view on the main thread? I also seems that you may have leak there. Why is the controller still allocated when you went back.

Comment: I am updating on the main thread. 
This is weird. I query the server in the background and dispatch on main to update the `cv`. 
Somehow it still continues after dismissing and when it reaches the `performBatchUpdates` it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use DispatchWorkItem for achieving this as follows

```
let backgroundQueue = DispatchQueue.global()

var backgroundTask: DispatchWorkItem!

backgroundTask = DispatchWorkItem { [weak self] in
    // Perform background task
    if !backgroundTask.isCancelled { 
       return to main Queue
    }

    backgroundTask = nil // resolve strong reference cycle
}        
backgroundQueue.async(execute: backgroundTask)

// When you want to cancel the task    
backgroundQueue.async { [weak backgroundTask] in
        backgroundTask?.cancel()
}
```

Comment: nice tip, I'm trying this out

Comment: @IvanCantarino I have updated my answer for better understanding

Comment: Thank you. Taking the approach you've mentioned worked, thus I needed anyway to create `[weak self]` in order to avoid accessing any local object that could have been retained

Answer (score 0):

This is desirable in many cases where we should abort all the Server request. I prefer to perform all the clean up in the

```
deinit() {

  // Abort all your APIs and asynchronous call
  // Release all dependency
```

}

Along with this, always have a weak reference of your controllers and then perform optional binding in the response of the Asynchronous call.

```
Almofire.request(reqData: param, method: get.....) {
  [weak self] response in
   guard let safeSelfRef = self, let safeCollectionView = 
   safeSelfRef.collectionView else { return } 
  //Update view here
}
```

Comment: hmm... I haven't thought on creating weak references to the self before updating the views themselves.
I'll try what you've shown and I'll feedback :)